# Adverb position of "initially"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I wrote

> It is mainly a recursive function that **initially** is called with the root node of the DOM tree (body element) and traverses the nodes in the dept-first manner.

Should it be "that is initially called"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the style, adverbs are put at various places. There is no **one** rule on that. However, I'd write this as...

> *Mainly*, it is a recursive function that is *initially* called ....

Others may have their versions...